# How do I make a bootstrap dropdown as wide as its input-group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this:

[image: dropdown screenshot]

Here's the code

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul id="color-dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">black</a></li>
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">white</a></li>
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">red</a></li>
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">blue</a></li>
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">yellow</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ytqyowgt/

How do I make the dropdown list as wide as the input field + button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting:

```
.input-group-btn {
    position: static;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    width: 100%;
}
```

check the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/ytqyowgt/3/)

Comment: Huh? Did you try it in the fiddle? Doesn't do anything to the width for me

Comment: I was missing a part.. check it now

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Can you please explain how/why it works?

Comment: setting width 100% will get it the same width of parent, but if parent is relative don't work...

Comment: Yeah, setting the width to 100% was the first thing I tried :)

Comment: Ahh, bootstrap sets the position to "position: relative;", so we have to reset it to its default value of "position: static;". Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes, If you want to customize your theme might be better to have local stylesheet,otherwise using CDN you'll need to override...

Answer (score 0):

Change a bit the structure of your HTML :

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control">
                <ul id="color-dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">black</a></li>
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">white</a></li>
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">red</a></li>
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">blue</a></li>
                    <li class="input"><a href="#">yellow</a></li>
                </ul>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and CSS :

```
 .input-group-btn ul {
width:100%;
  }
```

The only thing is you loose the rounded corners on the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/ytqyowgt/4/

Comment: I lose the rounded corners, and also, the dropdown isn't as wide as input + button, it's only as wide as the input